# Setting tax for specific country?

Tags: magento2, tax

I am using **Magento 2.2.5** and I have 3 tax zones for Switzerland, one with 0%, one with 19% and one with 7%.

I also have a tax rule which includes there 3 tax zones. Anyway, whenever I go to the checkout and choose Switzerland as country, the price still includes 19% tax.

ANything setup the wrong way?

Comment: What are the zones you have selected?

Comment: The 3 for Switzerland